# Bypass Cache when in Dev Environment

Tags: caching, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

Case scenario:

`$dbResult = myEloquentClass::remember(60)->all();`

My results are being cached, which works great for a production environment.

However, i am finding myself removing the `remember` method in my development environment since i don't want to cache my database results.

This results in a lot of unnecessary removal/additions of code.

Is there a way to bypass the cache globally for eloquent's `remember` when in development environment?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2501

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In laravel - 4 edit the app/config/local/cache.php file and set the `driver` to `array`.

```
<?php
    return array(
        'driver' => 'array',
    );
```

For laravel 5 - edit the .env file and set the `CACHE_DRIVER` to `array`

```
CACHE_DRIVER=array
```

Answer (score 0):

As posted by @bogdan,

I switch my development `cache.php` config file's `driver` to `array`, and works as advertised.